# EmailAddress FormatException doesn't catch everything

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, exception

I'm trying to catch wrongly formatted email addresses using the following code:

```
        Try
            Dim address = New MailAddress(emailAddress.Text)
        Catch ex As FormatException
            CustomValidator1.IsValid = False
        Finally
            confirmEmailAddress.Focus()
        End Try
```

It catches most things but not something like this:

test@testcom

Notice the lack of a full stop before 'com'. This does not throw a FormatException. Is there any way around this other than adding a RegEx test for email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It does not throw an exception because it's a valid email address.

See what [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5) says:

> A domain name (or often just a "domain") consists of one or more
> components, separated by dots if more than one appears.

A more formal definition can be found in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1).

If you want to add more validation on it you wil have to use RegEx or other string check methods.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use regexes to check for a dot in the `MailAddress.Host`. Have a look:

```
Dim address = New MailAddress("someone@somewhere")
If (address.Host.Contains(".") = False) Then
    CustomValidator1.IsValid = False
End If
```

Output:

[image]